# Linear Algebra: Orthogonal and perpendicular

Tags: linear-algebra

Simple and quick question. These two have to do with 90 degree angles.

This is the picture of the two words I have.

> Perpendicular is strictly restricted to lines.

- "Line A and B are perpendicular to each other."
- "v=(1, 1) and w=(-1, 1) -> cv and dw are perpendicular towards each other."

> Orthogonal is restricted to matrices.

```
1  1  1  1   
1 -1  1 -1  
1  1 -1 -1   
1 -1 -1  1
```

- The above matrix is an orthogonal matrix.

So would be following statement be correct: A orthogonal matrix has vectors which are perpendicular towards each other?

Comment: Orthogonal is definitely used in terms of pairs of vectors. One reason is that the inner product on your vector space might not have a natural geometric meaning. It's particularly weird to call two complex vectors 'perpendicular.'

Answer (score 1):

Usually the term "orthogonal matrix" is reserved for matrices whose columns are not only mutually perpendicular, but also unit vectors. So if you were to divide each entry in your matrix above by $2$, it would be an orthogonal matrix.

There appears to be no standard term for a matrix whose columns are just orthogonal without any restriction on their norms.

Comment: Matrices with unit norm columns are called orthonormal matrices.

Comment: @KarthikUpadhya See (for example, one among many) [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_matrix).

Comment: Sorry, my bad :)

Comment: One way to say it is the columns (or rows) of an orthogonal matrix form an orthonormal basis.  Of course orthogonal is usually said of *real* matrices.  The complex matrix property that generalizes this is that of a [unitary matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unitary_matrix).

Answer (score 0):

Yep. Perpendicular to each other in a higher dimensional space ( 4 dimensions in your example ).

In fact, you can write out the angle $\theta$ between two vectors $x,y$ as

$$cos(\theta) = \frac{x^T y}{\sqrt{x^T x} \sqrt{y^T y}} $$

Comment: Is the angel always 90 degrees in nxn or mxn orthongonal matrices?

Comment: @Karl Yes. Orthogonal matrices have columns that have a zero dot product with each other. Plug that into the above expression and you get $\theta = \pi/2$

Answer (score 0):

> Perpendicular is strictly restricted to lines.

"perp, short for perpendicular complement" can have more dimensions.
This in an article named [orthogonal component](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_complement).

So it is not just for lines.

- *perpendicular* comes from Latin (hanging down)
- *orthogonal* from greek (right lines)

In general, these two words seem to be used in a synonymous way.

Some specific contexts have settled with a specific meaning,
which uses always one of the two words,
as it is for *orthogonal matrix* meaning real matrix $Q$ with $QQ^T=I$.
Word usage just settles over time,
possibly starting from an influential text, or more texts.

A different definition between the two words per text might still occur.
To avoid misunderstanding is the reason,
why every text repeats definitions.